# Slurm Config for limit the endtime for all new jobs on the cluster to a certain date

Tags: slurm

Our cluster has to be shutdown for an update in two weeks. We would like to let users use the cluster until the last day, but we want to make sure, no job can be started, which would end after the shutdown date. Is there an easy way to limit the runtime of slurm jobs to a certain date instead of a fixed period of time (like the usual 5 days).

Is there a way to do this easily, or do have a change the slurm config each day and restart the slurm daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLURM has a feature to make this easier.  The feature is called Resource Reservation, and in particular, it's the Maintenance functionality of Resource Reservation.

The following example using the scontrol command is taken directly from the SLURM documentation for [Reservation Creation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/reservations.html) :

```
scontrol create reservation starttime=2009-02-06T16:00:00 \
   duration=120 user=root flags=maint,ignore_jobs nodes=ALL
```